# Register and resolve generic class with Unity

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I have the following interfaces

```
public interface IPermission {
    string UserId { get; set; }
}

public interface IPermissionsService<T> : IService<T> where T: IPermission, new() {
    ICollection<T> GetAssignedPermissions(User user);
    ICollection<T> GetAvailablePermissions();
    void AddPermissions(IEnumerable<T> permissions);
    void RemovePermissions(IEnumerable<T> permissions);
}
```

And the following classes that implement them

```
public class ReportPermission: IPermission  {
    public ReportPermission() {}
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class OrderTrackingPermission: IPermission  {
    public OrderPermission() {}
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public object OtherProperties { get; set; }
    public string Enabled { get; set; }
}


public class PermissionsService<T>: Service<T>, IPermissionsService<T> where T: IPermission, new() {

    PermissionsService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository<T> repository) : base(unitOfWork, repository) { }

    public ICollection<T> GetAssignedPermissions(User user) {
        return GetAssignedPermissions(user.UserId);
    }

    public ICollection<T> GetAssignedPermissions(string userId) {
        return Repository.All().Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
    }

    public ICollection<T> GetAvailablePermissions() {
        return Repository.All().ToList();
    }

    public void AddPermissions(IEnumerable<T> permissions) {
        foreach (T item in permissions) {
            Repository.Add(item);
        }
        UnitOfWork.Save();
    }

    public void RemovePermissions(IEnumerable<T> permissions) {
        foreach (T item in permissions) {
            Repository.Remove(item);
        }
        UnitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

My intent is avoid to implement a concrete ReportPermissionService or OrderPermissionService, because the presentation layer must be agnostic to the type of permission.

And, finally, **my question**:
How register and then resolve the classes with unity. I tried the following, but with syntax errors

```
    //Are the 3 following lines correct?
    currentContainer.RegisterType<IPermission, ReportPermission>("ReportPermission");
    currentContainer.RegisterType<IPermission, OrderTrackingPermission>("OrderTrackingPermission");
    currentContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IPermissionsService<>), typeof(PermissionsService<>));


    //How do I resolve to PermissionService<ReportPermissions>?
   IPermissionsService<IPermission> permissionsService = IoC.IoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IPermissionsService>("ReportPermission");
```

The above line throws error: `'Customers.Authorizations.Entities.IPermission' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Customers.Authorizations.Services.IPermissionsService<T>'`

Comment: You defined `IPermissionsService<T>` with `T: IPermission, new()`. Interfaces can't be `new()`ed, as the compiler says.

Comment: Thanks! That resolve the compiler error syntax